# Install Sweetalert via Yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, yarnpkg, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to install the library Sweetalert via Yarn, but I'm getting this error:

`couldn't find file 'sweetalert' with type 'application/javascript'`

My steps were the followed:

- yarn add sweetalert
- in application.js: `//= require sweetalert`
- in application.scss:

  `*= require sweetalert`

  `*= require sweetalert/dist/sweetalert`

my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you didn't require the javascript file from the node modules directory. You can use sweetalert2, it works fine for me.

```
yarn add sweetalert2
```

In JS

```
//= require sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min
```

In CSS

```
*= require sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min
```